# What is the air crash featured in Queen's Innuendo official video?

Tags: aircraft-identification, accidents

There's a short cameo of a total destruction of a plane in Queen's Innuendo official video (2:11).

Here's the video itself:

And here is a screenshot of the most important frame:

[image]

Is anyone able to identify this particular air crash and the airplane involved?

Comment: I think a "more important frame" is a few seconds earlier, showing that this is a test aircraft in a controlled crash.

Comment: The problem is that only from this point of Queen's video we have a full screen view of the crash. While the moment described by you is shown only on a small screen, in a so called cinema with pseudo-audience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was a test crash of a DC-7 conducted by the Flight Safety Foundation under contract to the FAA and in conjunction with NASA (among other organizations) in 1964.

[Here is the FAA film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrIZd53Gl4E), and a [NASA report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19840013833.pdf).

Comment: And here's what the crash was used for: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/72395